# Как включить “Potentially unhandled rejection…” в gulp вместо Error:

Tags: gulp

Я не знаю что Я для этого сделала, но один из моих проектов отображает gulp errors как "Potentially unhandled rejection..." и gulp при этом никогда не вылетает, поэтому мне не нужно его перезапускать. Но ошибки в других проектах выглядят как Error: и бла бла бла и всегда вылетает.

Пожалуйста объясните мне что Я должна сделать чтобы все моих проекты отображали ошибки как "Potentially unhandled rejection..." и без вылетов

Всё это при использовании gulp watch

Answer (score 1):

Причиной была новая версия gulp less. Там ошибки вида "Potentially unhandled rejection..." + и не вылетает.